# Как закрыть окно в WPF после нажатия кнопки в этом окне?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется главная (MainPage) страница.

```
namespace WpfApp22
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var page = new Page1();
            this.Content = page;
        }
    }
}
```

Открываю новую page1 страницу.

В ней содержится 1 кнопка, в event-ах нажатия данный код

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

Выдает

> System.NullReferenceException

Как можно закрыть окно по нажатию на кнопку в WPF?

(visual studio 2017)

Comment: ...вам обязательно использовать `Page`?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Content = page;
```

Вы устанавливаете контент новой страницы, а не делаете навигацию.

```
this.NavigationService.GoBack();
```

Тут происходит навигация в никуда, так как никакой навигации не было, было только переназначение контента.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var page = new Page1();
    page.Owner = this;
    // this.Content = page; 
    /* Если раскомментировать, то выбросит исключение:
       Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" 
       Дополнительные сведения: Объект Window должен быть корнем дерева.
       Нельзя добавить объект Window как дочерний объект для Visual.*/
    page.Show();
}
```

В дочернем окне:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Owner.Close();
}
```

Теория тут: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx)

Но имейте ввиду, что закроются оба окна.